# 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Persistance Entity' Java

Tags: java, spring, entity, uri

so I'm doing my custom RDF triplet store and I'm finding this problem when creating the Entity of the Triple. I don't understand what is this error message.

Uri class:

```java
@Entity
public class Uri {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String uri;

    private static String DEFAULT_URI = "http://provisionalUri.com/";

    public Uri() {
        this.uri = "";
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = DEFAULT_URI + uri;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return this.uri;
    }
}
```

Triple class which prompts the error: "'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Persistance Entity' Java" on the Uri objects:

```java
@Entity
public class Triple {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Uri subject;

    private Uri predicate;

    private Uri object;
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Persistance Entity' Java on the Uri objects in the class Triplet

Comment: You need to define @OneToMany relationships between the Triple entity and the Uri entity. See here how to do that: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many